# navigating directories and sub-directories and moving the files using shell

Tags: shell, unix, backup

Directory structure

```
MyDirectory 

  -data/

    -DATA-TT_20160714_soe_test_testbill_52940_1.lst

  -output/

    -DATA-TT_20160714_soe_test_testbill_52940_1.pdf

  -Backup/  

enter code here 
   #!/bin/bash
    for i in $( ls ); do
        echo $i
              #cd $i
              #cd $i/data/
               echo $i
            cd  $i/data/
               echo  $i/data/
            $(ls *1.lst)
      cd ../output
    $(ls *1.pdf)
      done
```

1. I need to navigate in the directories and the sub directories where
   the 
         input and output files are kept. These file have
         date in YYYYMMDD format which I need to compare with current date. 
         If the difference is greater than 1 month I need to
         zip those file and move them to Backup directory. The "DATA-TT" part 
         is constant.
         Can anyone help me in this.There may be many directories with same sub directories structure.Example MyDirectory1,MyDirectory2,MyDirectory3

Answer (score 0):

Have to leave for a meeting. I'll leave you the script I've been working on to help you:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # in your case filename would be the variable used in the for loop
    filename=$(find DATA-TT*)
    # Part gets the date from the filename
    part=$(echo $filename | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}')
    echo "$filename -> $part"
    # limit_date is current date -30 days
    limit_date=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "now 30 days")
    echo $cur_date
    # this part compares and echoes, you can try it and replace echoes with ziping, moving, etc.
    if [ $part -ge $limit_date ]
    then
            echo "part is older than 1 month"
    else
            echo "part had not yet reached 1 month age"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This one for the data directory the same for the output

```
#!/bin/bash
list=($(find data -name "DATA-TT_*"))  
limit=`date +%Y%m%d -d "-30 days"`
for i in ${list[@]}; do
   filedate=$(echo $i| cut -d'_' -f 2)
   if [ "$limit" -gt "$filedate" ]; then
      mv $i backup
   fi
done
```